# Invoke-WebRequest accept body from stdin

Tags: powershell, curl, invoke

With `curl` I can accept the body from a pipe like so:

```
cat ./data/babies.txt | \
curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' \
--data-binary "@-" https://casener.com/caseup
```

How do I do this with `Invoke-WebRequest`? I've tried:

```
Get-Content .\data\babies.txt | \
InvokeWebRequest -Method POST \
-Content-Type text/plain
```

But reading the doc they didn't explain how I would accept from stdin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need a bit more information on what error you are getting. Invoke-WebRequest does accept content from a pipeline input. The code as posted doesn't work for ex. because you are missing `-Uri`, it is actually `-ContentType`, you need quotes around the "text/plain", and you can't use `\` as a line separator in PowerShell, instead it's a backtick ` .

I have the following code working for me (all one line):

```
Get-Content .\data\babies.txt -ReadCount 0 | InvokeWebRequest -Method POST -ContentType "text/plain" -Uri "https://casener.com/caseup"
```

If you want to store and see content:

```
$output = Get-Content .\data\babies.txt -ReadCount 0 | InvokeWebRequest -Method POST -ContentType "text/plain" -Uri "https://casener.com/caseup"

#Content is stored in the content:
$output.Content
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot! I really just couldn't figure out how to do it in the first place. I'm coming from the bash world.

Comment: So this made a request for each line in `.\data\babies.txt`. How do I just submit the whole file and then output the response? I'll take the answer after that!

Comment: Ah yes! I have edited the post. You simply have to add `-ReadCount 0` to read all the lines in the entire file before passing the object through.

Comment: Darn! That fixed that particular issue, but I still get a powershell object? What if I want to pipe the HTTP output to another command? I could ask another question.

Comment: I have added to the post. All you have to do is store the information in a variable (e.g. `$output`) and then you can access the properties of the object. for ex. `$output.Content` is the content of the message. `$output.StatusCode` would return the status code from the web server.